# How can I add EditText(s) and a CheckBox with a Button?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, android-checkbox

So I've been working on a small app for myself, as I realized using Microsoft Word to keep track of all the college courses I've completed towards my degree wasn't ideal. So I figured, why not make that my first app? It's simple, and it's doable for someone with no app experience like myself.

So, this was my initial idea, it's nothing special, just some EditText fields along with a CheckBox to mark each course complete. Note, there are actually seven of these, all wrapped in a "ScrollView".
[image: This is what I have currently.]

Then I had a different idea. Instead of having a set amount of courses and credits EditTexts and a CheckBox, I'd rather just have a button to "Add A Course". My problem is, I'm not sure how I would achieve this. I'm still fairly new to programming, only taken two Java classes so far.

Here is my code for my "MainActivity.java":

```
package exporian.collegetracker;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.InputType;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onCheckBoxChecked(View v) {
        final EditText course1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course1);
        final CheckBox checkBox1 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final EditText credits1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits1);
        final EditText course2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course2);
        final CheckBox checkBox2 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        final EditText credits2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits2);
        final EditText course3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course3);
        final CheckBox checkBox3 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        final EditText credits3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits3);
        final EditText course4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course4);
        final CheckBox checkBox4 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        final EditText credits4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits4);
        final EditText course5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course5);
        final CheckBox checkBox5 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        final EditText credits5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits5);
        final EditText course6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course6);
        final CheckBox checkBox6 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
        final EditText credits6 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits6);
        final EditText course7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course7);
        final CheckBox checkBox7 = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        final EditText credits7 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.credits7);

        ArrayList<CheckBox> checkBoxes = new ArrayList<>();
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox1);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox2);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox3);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox4);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox5);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox6);
        checkBoxes.add(checkBox7);

        ArrayList<EditText> courses = new ArrayList<>();
        courses.add(course1);
        courses.add(course2);
        courses.add(course3);
        courses.add(course4);
        courses.add(course5);
        courses.add(course6);
        courses.add(course7);

        ArrayList<EditText> credits = new ArrayList<>();
        credits.add(credits1);
        credits.add(credits2);
        credits.add(credits3);
        credits.add(credits4);
        credits.add(credits5);
        credits.add(credits6);
        credits.add(credits7);

        int numOfCheckBoxes = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < numOfCheckBoxes; i++) {
            if (checkBoxes.get(i).isChecked()) {
                courses.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                courses.get(i).setFocusable(false);
                courses.get(i).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
                credits.get(i).setEnabled(false);
                credits.get(i).setFocusable(false);
                credits.get(i).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
            } else {
                courses.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                courses.get(i).setFocusable(true);
                courses.get(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                courses.get(i).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                credits.get(i).setEnabled(true);
                credits.get(i).setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
                credits.get(i).setFocusable(true);
                credits.get(i).setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
            } // End of if else
        } // End of for loop
    } // End of onCheckBoxChecked
} // End of MainActivity
```

I realize I've probably gone about this a very "noobish" way, and my code could probably be a lot cleaner, but I'm still fairly new to Java and even newer to Android, so please bear with me.

The biggest thing that I am stuck on is instantiating the EditTexts and CheckBox. How would I go about that? I figured, for my "numOfCheckBoxes" I would just add 1 to it every time the "Add A Course" button is clicked, so the for loop would still work correctly, but how would I create the id's for each new EditText and CheckBox, such as "course1", "course2, "course3", etc.

P.S. I'm not looking for someone to make the app for me, or for everything to be handed to me, just some insight from someone more experienced than me, thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi first of all you have to create your own class that extends linear layout with horizontal orientation and add to it your sub-views (edit text , text text , check box ), this will allow you to create 1 instance of your view that contains all of the 3 views .

For example  :

```
public class MySingleLineInList extends LinearLayout {

public MySingleLineInList(Context context) {
    super(context);

      setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

      EditText courseET = new EditText(context);
      EditText creditsET = new EditText(context);
      CheckBox complteCB = new CheckBox(context);

      addView(courseET);
      addView(creditsET);
      addView(complteCB);
}
}
```

Then you must use ListView(which is also including scroll) with listview adapter for showing your views(MySingleLineInList), and on button click you can add more views to this list :

```
ListView myListView = new ListView(context);

MyListArrayAdaptapter myAdapter = new MyListArrayAdaptapter(context);

myListView.setAdapter(myAdapter);



public class MyListArrayAdaptapter extends ArrayAdapter<MySingleLineInList> {

    public MyListArrayAdaptapter(Context context){
          super(context, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    }

    public void addViewToList(MySingleLineInList l){
        add(l);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

Then on button click just use :

```
Button b = new Button(context);
      b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            myAdapter.addViewToList(new MySingleLineInList());

        }
    });
```

Please note this is only the concept of doing it , for more information about list view and how it works please read here :

http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Or just google for custom listview.

- about the id's thing you can set id to any view in android for later use,
  for example :

  ```
    MySingleLineInList demo = new MySingleLineInList(context);
    demo.setId(1);


    int thisCourseId  = demo.getId();
  ```

Comment: Great answer! It was mostly understandable for a novice like myself. I've tried this method, and got it to work with no compiler errors. However, it doesn't seem to work yet with the button. I assume there's more I'll need to do, probably with "activity_main.xml" file? I'm confused, I was perviously just setting the "OnClick" attribute on views to a method that I would create in my "MainActivity" file, but what do I set the "OnClick" for the button to now?

Comment: In android there is many ways of working , one way is as you said and this is the recommend one, to set it by xml and then you have method in main that actually triggered when you click on the BT . i prefer to use the method i mention in my answer , you can call the onbutton click event almost on any view in android w/o the xml thing. same for design , its called doing thing programaticly w/o xml . same for the design  you can use         EditText course1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.course1);
or           EditText course1 = new EditText(...) .

Comment: When you use view.setOnClickListener , the onClick(View v){} is triggred and you put what happen on click inside the {} scope , the reason its not working maybe because this is not the right way to use list view for custom view as i said its only example concept of doing it, please read and understand the link i gave you , you should use the getView() ovveride method inside myAdapter (:

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll read up on it some more and give it another shot!

Comment: Glad i could help (:

Answer (score 0):

You can  dynamically create an `EditText` like this -

```
    int counter = 1;
    final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    final EditText edit_text = new EditText(this);
    edit_text.setId(counter++);
    edit_text.setLayoutParams(lparams);
```

And add it to your parent layout.

```
yourParentLayout.addView(edit_text);
```

Similarly you can do for `CheckBox`.

Comment: this way ? how about this bad practice ? how about this way really hard to manage and control the code and app needs ?

Comment: If you want to dynamically add a view , you have to do this way.

Comment: _NO_  you have to create one view for every 3 element and you can done it with `recyclerView` or `ListView`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a RecyclerView to show your list of objects. Check out [this example.](http://www.androidhive.info/2016/01/android-working-with-recycler-view/)

Then whenever you want to add a new course, just create a new "Course" object and add it to the dataSet array.